# Dead links and Missing pages are redirecting itself to Main Page with certain exceptions - Wordpress Related

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I hope my problem can be solved through this forum

I wanted my site to handle dead and non-existent links by displaying the 404 error page- Instead I noticed that it redirects these  non-existent links and missing pages to the main page like for example - **www.mysite.com/non-existent-link** (redirects to) **www.mysite.com/non-existent-links** with no apparent changes to the url.

Another problem is, when accessing the following URL: **mysite.com/genre/comedy** - the intended page loads up fine  but upon accessing mysite.com/genre it redirects to the homepage when it is supposed to display the error page

Only Exception when the error page actually works is when, links such as these **www.mysite.com/+16476567** or **www.mysite.com/444** or **mysite.com/genre/gibberish** are in use.

I have spent hours modifying the htaccess with different parameters, used default setting for permalinks and tried tweaking the template. But all in vain

Wish someone could throw some light on the problem

Comment: If yuo havent seen it already, this might help http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page

Comment: tried it already...  no difference